# WP->Query get Custom Post ID from meta_value & meta_key

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying for a couple of hours to make this work - but for some reason its simply to difficult for me. I have a custom post_type 'house', and I want to find the post_id of my custom post_type with a meta_key and certain meta value.

Lets say i want to find post_id for a house with
meta_key='house_id'
meta_value='231sd1223'

How exactly would i do that with wp->query?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have the query even with a loop. However, querying meta values is making more DB queries, consider looping throught "house" post type and than doing something only if meta_value is equal the house number.

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'house' ),
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'house_id',
            'value'     => '231sd1223',
        ),
    ),
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "select post_id, meta_key from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_value = '231sd1223.'", ARRAY_A );
```